# How to make return value optional for a method,if possible?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, methods, return-value

I have a method `private static DataTable ParseTable(HtmlNode table)` and sometimes this method has no return value then I want to make return value optional, is it possible ?

I have tried with `if` condition.But there is error.

How can I make return value optional for the method if possible ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't make the return value optional.

Your two options are to either return a `null` or an empty `DataTable`:

```
return new DataTable();
```

OR:

```
return null;
```

Which one is right? It depends on your application logic and how much `null` checking you are willing to do in your calling functions.

**Update:** (following comment)

This is how to return conditionally (assumes a variable called dataTable):

```
 if(gotTable)
 {
   return dataTable;
 }
 else
 {
   return null;
 }
```

Comment: @Oded, But how can I write return statement in if condition like if table got then return datatable else null ?

Comment: @Oded,ok..I thought if we make return value conditionally it gives error.
thanks...Sir..

Answer (score 5):

That's what `null` is for. Your method may return no object by returning `null`.

Keep in mind that returning `null` may complicate matters for the callers as they must check for null before using the returned reference, so in some cases it may be better to return a [Null Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern).

Answer (score 4):

You could always return `null` to indicate that there is no meaningful return value.

Answer (score 2):

If your method is called ParseTable and it fails "Parse" a "Table", then it should throw an exception. The advantage of this is that the exception can give the caller information about why it couldn't parse (html was invalid, unexpected column etc). The problem with returning null is that an unexpected nullreference exception almost never tells you the *cause* of the problem.

The "right" way to make a method that tries to parse a table, but happily does nothing if no result could be found is:

```
public bool TryParseTable(HtmlNode table, out DataTable result){
    // your code...
    if(success)
    {
        result = //the table you parsed
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        result = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Ok, so "result" could be null after calling this method, but at least the caller is more inclined to use an `if` statement thanks to the return type and method name.

Comment: @Rob Fonseca-Ensor,What is  `out` in parameter for the method ?

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void ParseTable(HtmlNode table, out DataTable data)
{
   // do the parse, fill bool gotTable 
   data = gotTable ? new DataTable() : null;
}

private static void ParseTable(HtmlNode table)
{
   ParseTable(table, out null);
}
```

if caller need table

```
DataTable data;
ParseTable(table, out data);
```

if not

```
ParseTable(table);
```

**EDIT:** I can't find how to implement optional `out/ref` parameters. So maybe it's impossible until `.NET 4.0` or fully impossible.

Comment: @leppie: Yeap, my idea doesn't work :( Maybe optional parameters in .NET 4.0 could help